# How to customize Apple App Store Appearance?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, app-store

I have seen lately that there are some apps in the apple app store which have a customized design like the one in the photo below.

[image]

**How can I customize the appearance of my app in the Apple App Store?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some apps are featured by Apple. And sometimes, Apple asks to the seller to provide promotional artworks in order to promote an app on the App Store.

If Apple wants to promote your app, you will receive a promo art request and you will upload it through iTunes Connect.