# iOS App Store Banners / Promotional Art Work

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, promotions

On the iTunes store ( apps ), I want to add a background Banner and have a unique colored background whenver someone visits our app on iOS Device or iTunes app on Mac / Windows. Such background images are used by companies like [Linkedin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6L0V.jpg) and [Watsapp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jidv.jpg). Cant find any area in iTunesConnect - Promotional Art. Can anyone please assist.

Thanks a lot !

[image]

Comment: I believe this is only offered to apps that are offered the "featured" status

Comment: You can't, duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28705145/how-to-customize-apple-app-store-appearance and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40004973/custom-image-assets-for-use-in-the-app-store List goes on...